# Dotted line with similar length of the text box in another tab displayed in all other tabs of dragablz:TabablzControl wpf mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, material-design

I am using `dragablz:TabablzControl` with material design.first tab I have added text box. but all other tabs a dotted line of the similar length of text box is present. How can I remove this dotted line.If i use normal tab control no dotted line is present. dotted line is present when I am using `dragablz:TabablzControl`

Please see the code

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTabMenu.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFTabMenu"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:dragablz="clr-namespace:Dragablz;assembly=Dragablz"
        xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
        Title="CoreProgramm WPF TabMenu"  Height="400" Width="880" ResizeMode="NoResize" 
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow" >
    <Grid >
        <Grid  >
            <dragablz:TabablzControl SelectedIndex="0"
                                      FixedHeaderCount="4" >
                <TabItem >
                    <TabItem.Header>
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Home" Foreground="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueLightBrush}" />
                    </TabItem.Header>

                    <Grid  >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBox Name="TextBoxName" Width="200"
                                Text="Name"></TextBox>
                  
                    </Grid>
                </TabItem>

                <TabItem Header="Customer details" Cursor="Hand" >
     
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="Admin details" >
             
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="Supplier details" >
                 

                </TabItem>

            </dragablz:TabablzControl>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**App.xaml**

```
  <Application x:Class="BIExtractionUtilityTool.App"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BIExtractionUtilityTool"
                  xmlns:dragablz="clr-namespace:Dragablz;assembly=Dragablz"
                 
       
 xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
                 StartupUri="Views/MainWindow.xaml">
        <Application.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                     <!--primary color--> 
                    <ResourceDictionary>
                         <!--include your primary palette--> 
                        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/MaterialDesignColor.Blue.xaml" />
                        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                        
                                <!--include three hues from the primary palette (and the associated forecolours).
                                Do not rename, keep in sequence; light to dark.-->
                            
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueLightBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary100}"/>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueLightForegroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary100Foreground}"/>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary500}"/>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidForegroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary500Foreground}"/>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueDarkBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary700}"/>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueDarkForegroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary700Foreground}"/>
                    </ResourceDictionary>
    
                     <!--secondary colour--> 
                    <ResourceDictionary>
                         <!--include your secondary pallette--> 
                        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
                            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
                            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/MaterialDesignColor.Blue.xaml" />
                        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    
                        
                         <!--include a single secondary accent color (and the associated forecolour)--> 
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondaryAccentBrush" Color="{StaticResource Accent200}"/>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondaryAccentForegroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource Accent200Foreground}"/>
                    </ResourceDictionary>
    
                     <!--Include the Dragablz Material Design style--> 
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Dragablz;component/Themes/materialdesign.xaml"/>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    
                 <!--tell Dragablz tab control to use the Material Design theme--> 
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type dragablz:TabablzControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTabablzControlStyle}" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
    
        </Application.Resources>
    </Application>
```

Dotted line
[image]

Comment: @mm8 can you please have a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add the following implicit `Style` to your `App.xaml` or window:

```
<Style TargetType="materialDesign:BottomDashedLineAdorner">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @mm8 perfect fix. I tried by making `Borderthickness="0"` ,by this way dotted line will disappear but line in the text box also disappear. Your implicit style fix is awesome.we need to update only one place but it wont lose any design.once again thank you so much.