# WPF Material Design Textbox is showing through slides. Is there a workaround?

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design-in-xaml

I tried using a textbox inside a WPF Material Design transitioner slide. The textbox is visible even when changing slides.

[image]

A dotted line from the textbox on the next slide is visible, and viceversa.

[image]

Has anyone else encountered this issue? Is there any workaround I could use?

This is the xaml I used. I am using the transitioner control although I believe the flipper control causes a similar effect when used with textboxes.

```
<Grid>
    <materialDesign:Transitioner SelectedIndex="0">
        <materialDesign:TransitionerSlide>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock Text="Hello, this is my first page!" Margin="10"/>
                <TextBox materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Type your first text here!" Margin="10"/>
                <Button Command="{x:Static materialDesign:Transitioner.MoveNextCommand}" Content=">" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </materialDesign:TransitionerSlide>
        <materialDesign:TransitionerSlide>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock Text="Hello, this is my 2nd page!" Margin="15"/>
                <TextBox materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Type your second text here!" Margin="15"/>
                <Button Command="{x:Static materialDesign:Transitioner.MovePreviousCommand}" Content="&lt;" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="15"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </materialDesign:TransitionerSlide>
    </materialDesign:Transitioner>
</Grid>
```

I believe the issue *might* lie in the dotted line that appears when a textbox is disabled, so possibly by removing that, the textbox would no longer show through slides. But that's just my guess.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the best approach, please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62760971/dotted-line-with-similar-length-of-the-text-box-in-another-tab-displayed-in-all).

Try to add the following implicit style to your *App.xaml* or window:

```
<Style TargetType="materialDesign:BottomDashedLineAdorner">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I try several ways and I found solution

please set  `BorderThickness="0"` in textboxes like this

```
<TextBox materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Type your second text here!" Margin="10"  BorderThickness="0"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping the offending control in:

```
<AdornerDecorator>
</AdornerDecorator>
```

seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Hi problem is in your margin , please set all your margins to 10 like this

```
<Grid>
    <materialDesign:Transitioner SelectedIndex="0">
        <materialDesign:TransitionerSlide>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock Text="Hello, this is my first page!" Margin="10"/>
                <TextBox materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Type your first text here!" Margin="10"/>
                <Button Command="{x:Static materialDesign:Transitioner.MoveNextCommand}" Content=">" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </materialDesign:TransitionerSlide>
        <materialDesign:TransitionerSlide>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock Text="Hello, this is my 2nd page!" Margin="10"/>
                <TextBox materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Type your second text here!" Margin="10"/>
                <Button Command="{x:Static materialDesign:Transitioner.MovePreviousCommand}" Content="&lt;" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="15"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </materialDesign:TransitionerSlide>
    </materialDesign:Transitioner>
</Grid>
```

I hope it help you

Comment: Hi. I understand what you did, but unfortunately, that won't help on my real application, because I have some slides with textboxes, and some without. Ideally the textbox should only show on the slide it is on. Thanks anyway!